# DLL files error in using pytorch

Tags: python, dll, pip, pytorch

I add pytorch via pip installation and now I'm trying to use it, but have this dll error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Projects/1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I install msvcp71 and msvcr71 dll files but it's not worked!

Comment: "i install msvcp71 and msvcr71 dll files but it's not worked" installed where?  Generally, DLLs need to be on your `PATH` environment variable in order to be found by the loader, or in the same directory as the DLL they're being loaded from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out which dependency of that DLL might be missing. Use it to open the Python extension file that's failing to load. The file name should be something like:

```
C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.pyd
```

Another common cause is a DLL for Python 64-bit while using Python 32-bit or vice-versa. But you installed with `pip` so it should be OK. Nevertheless, it's a good idea to verify this is not the case.